# android - loading Bitmaps into array with UniversalImageLoader

Tags: android, arraylist, bitmap, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to fill arraylist with Bitmaps and here is my code:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    ArrayList<Bitmap> imgArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int num=0;num<4;num++) {
        imgArray.add(num,imageLoader.loadImageSync("http://example.com/sample.jpg"));
    }
```

But I'm getting a NullPointerException, though loadImageSync(uri) should've returned Bitmap as stated in the Documentation on GitHub. How to fix the problem?

Comment: Did you initialize the ImageLoader? (`ImageLoader.getInstance().init(<CONFIG>);`)

Comment: Cannot write "CONFIG" this way. It leads to Bitmap.Config, but after it something is still not ok

Comment: How to initialise configuration? Give me an example plz

Comment: @MarcoBatista could you please help me with initializing config?

Comment: Sorry I have been away for the day, but I see that hasan83 has already pointed int he right direction :)

Comment: @MarcoBatista yes, but my problem isn't still solved :) I'm still having some issues to struggle and a bit later I'll post the link to my new question about this topic

Comment: @MarcoBatista the link for my related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777399/android-delay-while-loading-bitmaps-into-arraylist-using-universalimageloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration:

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "/sdcard/Android/data/random_folder_name_for_cache");

        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getApplicationContext()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                .discCache(new FileCountLimitedDiscCache(cacheDir, 100))
                .build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);


final ArrayList<Bitmap> imgArray = new ArrayList<>(); // this should be a public array outside of the method scope. a member of the activity
for (int num=0;num<4;num++) {
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); 
    int final constNum = num;
    imageLoader.loadImage("http://example.com/sample.jpg", new SimpleImageLoadingListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) 
        {
           imgArray.add(constNum, loadedImage);
        }
    });        
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85076/discussion-on-answer-by-hasan83-android-loading-bitmaps-into-array-with-univer).